# Python: Waiting for a file to reach a size limit in a CPU friendly manner

Tags: python, multithreading, sleep, polling

I am monitoring a file in Python and triggering an action when it reaches a certain size. Right now I am sleeping and polling but I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this:

```
POLLING_PERIOD = 10
SIZE_LIMIT = 1 * 1024 * 1024
while True:
    sleep(POLLING_PERIOD)
    if stat(file).st_size >= SIZE_LIMIT:
        # do something
```

The thing is, if I have a big POLLING_PERIOD, my file limit is not accurate if the file grows quickly, but if I have a small POLLING_PERIOD, I am wasting CPU.

Thanks!

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What specific platform if any are you targeting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Linux Solution**

You want to look at using [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) it is a Python binding for [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

Here is an example on watching for `close` events, it isn't a big jump to listening for size changes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys
from pyinotify import WatchManager, Notifier, ProcessEvent, EventsCodes

def Monitor(path):
    class PClose(ProcessEvent):
        def process_IN_CLOSE(self, event):
            f = event.name and os.path.join(event.path, event.name) or event.path
            print 'close event: ' + f

    wm = WatchManager()
    notifier = Notifier(wm, PClose())
    wm.add_watch(path, EventsCodes.IN_CLOSE_WRITE|EventsCodes.IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE)

    try:
        while 1:
            notifier.process_events()
            if notifier.check_events():
                notifier.read_events()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        notifier.stop()
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        path = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        print 'use: %s dir' % sys.argv[0]
    else:
        Monitor(path)
```

**Windows Solution**

pywin32 has bindings for file system notifications for the Windows file system.

What you want to look for is using [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx) and tie into that and list for `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE`. This example listens for File Name change it isn't a big leap to listen for size changes.

```
import os

import win32file
import win32event
import win32con

path_to_watch = os.path.abspath (".")

#
# FindFirstChangeNotification sets up a handle for watching
#  file changes. The first parameter is the path to be
#  watched; the second is a boolean indicating whether the
#  directories underneath the one specified are to be watched;
#  the third is a list of flags as to what kind of changes to
#  watch for. We're just looking at file additions / deletions.
#
change_handle = win32file.FindFirstChangeNotification (
  path_to_watch,
  0,
  win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME
)

#
# Loop forever, listing any file changes. The WaitFor... will
#  time out every half a second allowing for keyboard interrupts
#  to terminate the loop.
#
try:

  old_path_contents = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
  while 1:
    result = win32event.WaitForSingleObject (change_handle, 500)

    #
    # If the WaitFor... returned because of a notification (as
    #  opposed to timing out or some error) then look for the
    #  changes in the directory contents.
    #
    if result == win32con.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
      new_path_contents = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
      added = [f for f in new_path_contents if not f in old_path_contents]
      deleted = [f for f in old_path_contents if not f in new_path_contents]
      if added: print "Added: ", ", ".join (added)
      if deleted: print "Deleted: ", ", ".join (deleted)

      old_path_contents = new_path_contents
      win32file.FindNextChangeNotification (change_handle)

finally:
  win32file.FindCloseChangeNotification (change_handle)
```

**OSX Solution**

There is equivalent hooks into the OSX file system using PyKQueue as well, but if you can understand these examples you can Google for the OSX solution as well.

Here is a good article about [Cross Platform File System Monitoring](http://www.stepthreeprofit.com/2008/06/cross-platform-monitoring-of-filesystem.html).

Answer (score 2):

You're correct: "Polling is Evil".  The more often you poll, the more you waste CPU if nothing happened.  If you poll less frequently, you delay handing the event when it does occur.

The only alternative, however, is to "block" until you receive some kind of "signal".

If you're on Linux, you can use "inotify":

http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify

Comment: Won't inotify still waste CPU?

Answer (score 1):

You're right that polling is generally a sub-optimal solution compared to other ways of accomplishing something. However, sometimes it's the simplest solution, especially if you are trying to write something that will work on both Windows and Linux/UNIX.

Fortunately, modern hardware is quite fast.  On my machine, I was able to run your loop, polling ten times a second, without any visible impact on the CPU usage in the Windows Task Manager. 100 times a second did produce some tiny humps on the usage graph and the CPU usage would occasionally reach 1%.

Ten seconds between polling, as in your example, is utterly trivial in terms of CPU usage.

You can also give your script a lower priority to make sure it doesn't affect the performance of other tasks on the machine, if that's important.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a kludge, but given the CPU load vs. Size accuracy conundrum, would a **variable polling period** be appropriate?

In a nutshell, the the polling period would decrease as the file size approaches the limit and/or as the current growth rate is above a certain level. In this fashion, at least most of the time, the CPU load cost of the polling would be somewhat reduced.

For example, until the current file size reaches a certain threshold (or a tiers of thresholds), you'd allow for a longer period.
Another heuristic: if the file size didn't change since last time, indicating no current activity on the file, you could further boost the period by a fraction of a second.  (Or comparing the timestamp of the file with current time may do?).

The specifics parameters of the function that determine the polling period given the context will depend on the particulars of the way the file growth takes place in general.

- What is the absolute minimal amount of time for the file to grow to say 10% of the size limit?
- What is the average amount of data written to these files in 24 hours?
- Is there much difference in the file growth rate at different times of day and night ?
- What is the frequency at which the file size changes?
  Is it a "continuous" logging-like activity, whereby on average several dozen of writes take place each second, or are the writes taking place less frequently but putting much more data at once when they do?
- etc.

Alternatively, but at the risk of introducing *OS-specific logic* in your program, you can look into **file/directory changes notification** systems.  I know that both the WIN32 API and Linux offer their flavor of this kind of feature.  I'm unaware of the specific implementation the OSes use, and these may well introduce some kind of polling approach similar to what you have externally.  Yet, the OS has various hooks into the file system that may allow it a much less intrusive implementation.

Comment: Another interesting heuristic would be to estimate how quickly the file is filling up, and poll more frequently as it nears the limit. I guess that is sort of like your first idea but I was thinking of a more continuous function.

Comment: @kindall: yes, the function needn't be discrete.  There's a bit of a catch 22 in trying to integrate too closely the growth rate into the heuristics/function because doing so would imply having a relatively reliable measure of the "instantaneous" growth rate and such would in turn imply a more frequent sampling ;-).  Much of the details for a variable polling period system depends on the statistical elements mentioned in the question.  My  inclination would be to go for a relatively simple polling-based system (maybe a few tiers and some easy heuristics) or otherwise go the Notification route.